Nginx Return 200 status code in body to client , but empty postdata sent to backend endpoint proxy_pass in upload
In the example location of nginx I need to reply to the client hit the 200 status code of http protocol in body and send the POST data of the client to the backend.
When I configure in location the return 200 message the post of the client is lost
And the log: "POST /service HTTP/1.1" 200 65 "-" "Client" - Cache: - - - - Postdata: -
Location config:
    location ~  /service{
    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '{"OK": {"status_code": 200,"status": "OK"}}';
    proxy_pass http://serverbackend;
    }

In the client it works fine the json is ok but the POST data of the message is lost.
¿It's possible to have both?
Thanks.
